# Want to convert a nested object to query parameter for attaching to url

Tags: javascript, query-string

Hi I need to construct to url request with query parameter, I have a nested object with the key and values, like below

```
 "user": {
    "first_name": "Srini",
    "last_name": "Raman",
     "gender": "male",
     "dob": "1992-08-02",
     "address_attributes": {
      "city": "San Diego",
      "state": "CA",
      "zip": 92127,
      "country": "USA",
      "latitude": 37.257009,
      "longitude": -120.050767
    }
}
```

i need to get a query parameter like

```
user[first_name]=Srini&user[last_name]=Raman&user[address_attributes][city]=San Diego&user[address_attributes][state]=CA
```

Comment: what did you try ?

Comment: I tried using https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string
queryString.stringify(data)

but the result was like 
```
user_firstname=Srini&user_address=%5Bobject%20Object%5D
```

Comment: why not use Axios which will handle URL encoding for you.

Comment: can Axios create the url parameter like user[address_attributes][city]=San Diego&user[first_name]=Srini

i will try and will update you

Comment: Tried Axios but when i was passing the user option url was not former corrected it was not encoding
/api/v1/users?[object Object]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```js
let obj = {
  user: {
    first_name: 'Srini',
    last_name: 'Raman',
    gender: 'male',
    dob: '1992-08-02',
    address_attributes: {
      city: 'San Diego',
      state: 'CA',
      zip: 92127,
      country: 'USA',
      latitude: 37.257009,
      longitude: -120.050767
    }
  }
};

let getPairs = (obj, keys = []) =>
  Object.entries(obj).reduce((pairs, [key, value]) => {
    if (typeof value === 'object')
      pairs.push(...getPairs(value, [...keys, key]));
    else
      pairs.push([[...keys, key], value]);
    return pairs;
  }, []);

let x = getPairs(obj)
  .map(([[key0, ...keysRest], value]) =>
    `${key0}${keysRest.map(a => `[${a}]`).join('')}=${value}`)
  .join('&');
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [qs](https://npmjs.com/package/qs) package.

Their `stringify` method seems to do exactly what you want.

Usage example:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  const obj = {
    "user": {
      "first_name": "Srini",
      "last_name": "Raman",
      "gender": "male",
      "dob": "1992-08-02",
      "address_attributes": {
        "city": "San Diego",
        "state": "CA",
        "zip": 92127,
        "country": "USA",
        "latitude": 37.257009,
        "longitude": -120.050767
      }
    }
  };

  console.log(Qs.stringify(obj, { encode: false }));
}, {
  once: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qs/6.11.0/qs.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: please add more info from the mentioned site in your answer. Otherwise its a "link only" answer, which might get deleted by the community.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30820290)

Comment: Very nice and easy library to use, I recommand, thanks for sharing

Comment: That works but is incredibly bloated IMHO for the job. Looks like `query-string` module now does serialize nested objects for a much smaller payload.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a TypeScript implementation if someone needs it.

```
const testObject = {
  "user": {
    "first_name": "Srini",
    "last_name": "Raman",
    "gender": "male",
    "dob": "1992-08-02",
    "address_attributes": {
      "city": "San Diego",
      "state": "CA",
      "zip": 92127,
      "country": "USA",
      "latitude": 37.257009,
      "longitude": -120.050767
    }
  }
}

interface ObjectToQueryStringHelperObject {
  keyPath: Array<string>;
  value: boolean | number | string;
}

function objectToQueryStringHelper(
  object: any,
  path: Array<string> = [],
  result: Array<ObjectToQueryStringHelperObject> = []
): Array<ObjectToQueryStringHelperObject> {
  return Object.entries(object).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    if (!_.isNil(value) || !_.isEmpty(value)) {
      _.isObject(value) ?
        acc.push(...objectToQueryStringHelper(value, [...path, key], result)) :
        acc.push({ keyPath: [...path, key], value });
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

export function objectToQueryString(object: any): string {
  const simplifiedData = objectToQueryStringHelper(object);
  const queryStrings = simplifiedData.map(({ keyPath: [firstKey, ...otherKeys], value }) => {
    const nestedPath = otherKeys.map(key => `[${key}]`).join('');
    return `${firstKey}${nestedPath}=${!_.isNil(value) ? encodeURI(`${value}`) : ''}`
  })
  return queryStrings.join('&');
}

console.log(objectToQueryString(testObject))
```

Comment: probably want to use `encodeURIComponent` instead of `encodeURI`

Answer (score 0):

converted [fr1sk answer] to vanilla js.
(no ts & no lodash requirement)
also changed encodeURI to [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) as suggested by Alex:

> The encodeURIComponent() function encodes a URI by replacing each instance of certain characters ...
> Compared to encodeURI(), this function encodes more characters,
> including those that are part of the URI syntax.

```js
function objectToQueryStringHelper(object, path, result) {
    return Object.entries(object).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
        if ((value != null) || (value?.length != 0)) {
            typeof value === 'object'
                ? acc.push(
                      ...objectToQueryStringHelper(
                          value,
                          [...path, key],
                          result
                      )
                  )
                : acc.push({ keyPath: [...path, key], value });
        }
        return acc;
    }, []);
}

export function objectToQueryString(object) {
    const simplifiedData = objectToQueryStringHelper(object, []);
    const queryStrings = simplifiedData.map(
        ({ keyPath: [firstKey, ...otherKeys], value }) => {
            const nestedPath = otherKeys.map((key) => `[${key}]`).join("");
            return `${firstKey}${nestedPath}=${
                (value != null) ? encodeURIComponent(`${value}`) : ""
            }`;
        }
    );
    return queryStrings.join("&");
}
```